# Instantiate all properties and sub properties in an object (C#.net)

Tags: c#, .net, recursion, reflection, properties

I have an object (x) with about 100 properties. Most of these properties are reference types that will need to be instantiated before I can do anything with x. Also, many of the properties on x will have properties that will also need to be instantiated.

I've thought to use reflection and recursion, but I'm still a little bit stuck on how the implementation would work. My current implementation involves looping through the PropertyInfo Array, and using SetValue from Activator.CreateInstance. As I drill down through x, I'm getting a lot of exceptions:

- No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
- Cannot create an abstract class.
- Property set method not found.

Should I just account for these cases, or is there a better way to be doing this? Ultimately, it's not assigning values to everything I need still. Thanks for your help.

Comment: can you modify the code for `object(x)`?

Comment: All of those problems would be problems in a normal hard-coded approach. I suggest you first write (and get working) the simple-but-longwinded code, so you can *then* convert it to use reflection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably this is overkill, but having such a big object which appears to refer to a hierarchy of classes (you mentioned abstract classes), I'd use a properly configured DI container such as Unity, to do the work for me.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for Dependency Injection, .NET included Managed Extensibility Framework, which supports creating objects with properties and with proper lifecycle control.

However, it will still give exceptions when it cannot instantiate types, but instead of creating all types, MEF provides attributes and other ways to control what types should be instantiated.